# Can the compiler deal with the initialization order of static variables correctly if there is dependency?

Tags: c++, static-members

Can the compiler deal with the initialization order of static variables correctly if there is dependency? For example, I have

`a.h`:

```
struct A { static double a; };
```

`a.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"
double A::a = 1;
```

`b.h`:

```
struct B { static double b; };
```

`b.cpp`:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"
double B::b = A::a;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `A.cpp` fail to compile due to duplicate definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within translation units the order of such initialization is specified. Across translation units the order is not specified.

So in your case, since statics will get zero initialized by default, `B::b` will definitely be 0 or 1.

Comment: Wow. So the short answer is unfortunately `no`. Thanks. I have a new related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834855/can-the-compiler-deal-with-the-initialization-order-of-static-variables-correctl

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Static initialization order is undefined by the C++ standard. You can HOPE that your compiler is smart, but there's no guarantee.

Think about what would happen if you also have a "c" variable which is assigned with "b", and the "a" variable is assigned with "c". Then you've have a circular dependency, and it would compile, but you would end up with garbage values.