# Can the compiler deal with the initialization order of static variables correctly?

Tags: c++, static-members

How about the following case? Can the compiler deal with the initialization order of static variables correctly if there is dependency?

a.h

```
template<class T>
struct A { static double a; };

template<class T>
double A<T>::a = 1;
```

b.h

```
struct B { static double b; };
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

double B::b = A<int>::a;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1421736/2718447

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211237/static-variables-initialisation-order

Comment: In this case, there's no issue since `a` is initialised statically. Presumably, you're asking about the more general case where both require dynamic initialisation?

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Isn't the initialization of `B::b` dynamic, since `A<int>::a` is not a constant expression?

Comment: @VaughnCato: You're right; I should have said "no issue since `a` is initialised statically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `A<int>::a` is initialized statically, and all static initialization takes place before any dynamic initialization.  `B::b` is initialized dynamically and so it will happen after `A<int>::a` is initialized, and everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, there is no issue since `a` is initialised statically; this is guaranteed to happen before the dynamic initialisation of `b`.

More generally, where both require dynamic initialisation, this *is* an issue. Unless you specialise the template member before using it to initialise `b`, there is no guaranteed order. To quote the standard (C++11 3.6.2/2):

> Definitions of explicitly specialized class template static data members have **ordered initialization**. Other class template static data members (i.e., implicitly or explicitly instantiated specializations) have **unordered initialization**.